# Flux for a differential equation describes a manifold.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

The book I'm reading defines lines of flux of a vector field $F(x) \in C^1$ with bounded partial derivatives, by defining a function $\varphi(t,x_0)$, that is the solution of the differential equation with initial data $(0,t_0)$. Now, given a $C^1$ 2-manifold $S$ that "cuts" some lines of flow a single time, I get that the surface $S'=\varphi_t(S)$ (where $\varphi_t$ is $\varphi$ for fixed $t$) is a $C^1$ 2-manifold. However the thing that the book takes as a given, is that the set formed by lines of flow and bounded by two surfaces that cuts lines of flow a single time is a $C^1$ 2-manifold, at least with a negligible set of singularities, and I don't know how to prove this.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.